# Mock a response of a inner function but test the outer function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have a C# code setup this way.

```
public class Client : IClient
{
    public string funcA()
    {
       var output = funcB(1);
       //Do something on output and produce finalResult
       return finalResult;
    }

    public string funcB(int x)
    {
         // Some operations on produces string result
         return result;
    }
}
```

I want to mock funcB output but let the funcA perform as is based on the output from funcB.

In my test class I do the following:

```
public class MockClient
{
    private Mock<IClient> _mockClient;

    public MockClient()
    {
        _mockClient = new Mock<IClient>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestClient()
    {
        _mockClient.Setup(foo => foo.funcB(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns("test");
        var testOutput = _mockClient.Object.funcA();
    }
}
```

The variable testOutput returns NULL. I understand why, because the object is created from an Interface. I am not sure how to exactly work around this problem. Any inputs on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Moq based off of your syntax? If so, you can use "Partial Mocks". Example:

Change funcB to be **virtual**

```
public virtual string funcB(int x)
{
    // Some operations on produces string result
    return result;
}
```

Then mock the concrete type and set the CallBase property to true:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestClient()
{
    Mock<Client> _mockClient = Mock<Client>();
    _mockClient.CallBase = true;
    _mockClient.Setup(foo => foo.funcB(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns("test");
    var testOutput = _mockClient.Object.funcA();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but it works even without making CallBase = true. Whats its significance here? Also the part about making virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Example above is totally correct in Moq syntax. But making the functions virtual or not - it's a production decision based on your, client, etc purposes and needs. Changing funcB to be virtual just for test - sounds unreasonable.

You can use [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/) for testing your original code, see:

```
     public class Client : IClient
     {
        public string funcA()
        {
            var output = funcB(1);
            //Do something on output and produce finalResult
            var finalResult = "B result: " + output;
            return finalResult;
        }

        public string funcB(int x)
        {
            // Some operations on produces string result
            return "result";
        }
    }

    [TestMethod, Isolated]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //Arrange
        var foo = new Client();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => foo.funcB(0)).WillReturn("test");

       //Act
       var output = foo.funcA();

       //Assert
       Assert.AreEqual("B result: test", output);
   }
```